# Is it possible to intercept Console output?

Tags: c#, .net, .net-3.5, console

I call a method, say, `FizzBuzz()`, over which I have no control.  This method outputs a bunch of stuff to the Console using `Console.WriteLine`.

Is it possible for me to intercept the output being generated by the `FizzBuzz` method?
Note that my application is a Console app itself.

Answer (score 75, accepted):

Yes, very much possible:

```
var consoleOut = new StringWriter();
Console.SetOut(consoleOut);
Console.WriteLine("This is intercepted."); // This is not written to console
File.WriteAllText("ConsoleOutput.txt", consoleOut.ToString());
```

Later on if you want to stop intercepting the console output, use modification below:

```
var stdOut = Console.Out;
// Above interceptor code here..
Console.SetOut(stdOut); // Now all output start going back to console window
```

Or the [OpenStandardOutput](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/16f09842.aspx) does the same without the need to save the standard stream first:

```
// Above interceptor code here..
var standardOutput = new StreamWriter(Console.OpenStandardOutput());
standardOutput.AutoFlush = true;
Console.SetOut(standardOutput); // Now all output starts flowing back to console
```

Comment: Don't forget to save `Console.Out` before doing this so you can restore it.

Comment: @Rick: Unless someone has already switched it out! :) `Console.OpenStandardOutput()` will always give you the real one.

Comment: @Porges: If `FizzBuzz` has the same point of view we are out of luck :-)

Comment: @Teoman Soygul: worth noting, that this only works if FizzBuzz is executed in the same appdomain. It most likely not an issue for the OP, just noting, for completeness.

Comment: @Teoman: you need to set it using `SetOut` as well, that just retrieves the stream.

Comment: What about intercepting colored output: i.e.:
`var oldColor = Console.ForegroundColor;
Console.ForegroundColor = color ?? oldColor;
Console.Write(message);
Console.ForegroundColor = oldColor;`

Comment: @Porges: Following the "what if everyone did this?" rule, it is often better to save and restore `Console.Out` than to use `Console.OpenStandardOutput()`.  Like the OP's program, any other utility which swapped out `Console.Out` may have a dependency on that behavior.

Comment: I assume this won't work if the Console output is coming from a native library called from .NET wrapper library called from my code, right?