# How to redirect the output of a compiled matlab script?

Tags: c#, .net, matlab, matlab-compiler

I have been given some matlab code compiled using the .net compiler.

I can run it just fine from a console application, but if there are some warnings, they are printed in the command window.

I would like to be able to either hide them, or print them somewhere else.

How can I redirect that standard output for a portion of code (not a separate process)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can redirect console output to any stream. Have a look at this: [Is it possible to intercept Console output?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6024172/is-it-possible-to-intercept-console-output)